# create pdf from multiple excel sheets and tabs in Java

Tags: excel, pdf-generation, jodconverter

I want to read some excel files with multiple sheets in it.

All sheets should be printed 2 on 1 in a pdf.

I've found the [jodconverter](http://code.google.com/p/jodconverter/) library. 
If there are better or easier opinions please tell me.

[image: simplified descripton of the text]

May important:
i don't want to change something in the xls files, if not necessary.

EDIT:
Following approach, merging all the xls with [apache poi](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html) and print them to one pdf, I think i need a option to configure the "printer". How can I do that?

### EDIT2:

I've found a way to print directly xls to pdf with the [jxcell-library](http://www.jxcell.net/). There is an [example](http://www.jxcell.net/features.htm) for printing a pdf from a xls file. But mutliple spreadsheet arent listend. So i'll going to seperate them with poit, print them to pdf, and merge it.

If you know a faster or easyier solution, feel free to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it:

1. Read excel data using the [apache poi](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html) library.
2. Make a loop to generate html tables based on the data you get from apache poi.
3. Use [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/downloads/list) to generate pdf out of that html.